# Redirect to a url if a custom url parameter appear

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

how can i redirect a url to other url with selected url parameter using **htacess**

that is if customer enter a url like

`http://exmaple.com/?par_1=%string&par_2=%string&par_3=%string`

then i  want to remove url parameter 1 and 3 and redirect with par_2 value  .

That is

```
http://exmaple.com/?par_2=%string.
```

How it can be done ?  Here `% string` will be anything .

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?par_1=([^&]+)&par_2=([^&]+)&par_3=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://exmaple.com/?par_2=%2 [L,R]
```